# How do I redirect the URL depending on the subdomain?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a subdomain-specific redirection I am currently on. Is possible to make the redirection depends of subdomain?

Is it possible to do subdomain-specific redirection?

The Polish version of my website:
mywebsite.pl

English version:
en.mywebsite.pl

I have this in my .htaccess file:

`# Change WordPress search URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /oferty/\?search_keywords=%1 [R=301,L]`

But there is problem that the redirection works only for Polish version (even I am using English subdomain) - it redirects to mywebsite.pl

Now I would like to redirect:

If is `en.mywebsite.pl`

Redirect the args: `?s=TEST`

For `en.mywebsite.pl/jobs/?search_keywords=TEST`

But if is the Polish version `mywebsite.pl`

Redirect it for: `mywebsite.pl/oferty/?search_keywords=TEST`

Can somone help me with it?

I really do not know how to make it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help.

I found solution by myself:

For the English version:

`# Change WordPress search URL
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?en.mywebsite.pl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /jobs/\?search_keywords=%1 [R=301,L]`

And for the Polish version:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsite.pl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /oferty/\?search_keywords=%1 [R=301,L]`

Grettings!